# How to identify zipped file which is having my own extension through my App

Tags: android

My requirement is like,

In my app I want to send some files as an email attachment by compressing into a single file which is having my own extension say(samplefile.myownext).

Assume that the receiver's(email) end also my app is already installed.

Now when I am clicking on the attachment, I want to show option "Open with myApp" and need to open with my app.

For this what are the steps I need to follow.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mention `host` and `scheme` attributes in `intent-filter` of your activity.

lets say your file extension is `.myownext` define the `intent-filter` like this:
`<intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
     <data android:scheme="file" />
     <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
     <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.myownext" />
     <data android:host="*" />
</intent-filter>`

The `pathPattern` attribute specifies a complete path that is matched against the complete path in the Intent object, and also these attributes are meaningful only if the `scheme` and `host` attributes are also specified for the filter.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am able to do it.

Comment: pleasure to help you :)

Comment: But I can't do it for all email clients, I can do it for Gmail and not for Native mail client

Comment: Any idea about native mail client..